# Cross-Domain Access Error Calling WCF Service from Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I have a WCF service hosted within a Windows service. Its purpose is to receive uploaded files. I want to be able to upload via a silverlight application. I can connect to the webservice but as soon as i call a method when it returns i get an security exception saying somehing about a crossdomain policy. I got a clientaccesspolicy.xml file, but where do i put it for it to work? And is this really the problem?

It should be noted that the webservice is working as intended i have other clients using it, a winForms application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a clientaccesspolicy.xml file on your server if you're calling the service from Silverlight. It should be located at the root of your website/domain. As an alternative you can run your Silverlight out-of-browser and with elevated permissions (just for testing) - then you don't need the clientaccesspolicy.xml file.

Comment: But i do not have a website. As i mentioned, im hosting the service in a Windows service/winforms applikation.

Comment: Have you tried the out-of-browser + elevated permissions - just for testing?